# A pointer variable in C++ points only to variables in the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers

According to Warford's "Computer Systems" (4th ed), "When you declare a global or local variable, you specify its type. For example, you can specify the type to be an integer, or a character, or an array. Similarly, when you declare a pointer, you must declare that it points to some type. The pointer itself can be global or local. The value to which it points, however, resides in the heap and is neither global nor local."

I know that you can create local variables in the stack, global variables in a fixed location, and dynamically allocated variables in the heap. Can pointers only point to dynamically allocated variables then? Why can't a pointer point to global or local variables?

Thanks

Comment: They can point to local variables: `int a = 0; int* p = &a;`.

Comment: Are you sure the context of the book is C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The value to which it points, however, resides in the heap and is neither global nor local.

That is incorrect.

> Can pointers only point to dynamically allocated variables then?

No.

> Why can't a pointer point to global or local variables?

They sure can.

---

You might want to read the book more carefully to see whether the statement in book was made with some additional context. If not, it's time to abandon the book and learn from a different one.

Comment: yeah the book seems a little off

Comment: BTW, you can read "A Tour of C++" online at https://isocpp.org/tour if you are not in a position to invest in a good book.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer point to the place in memory where the variable is located. I don't think you should care about where it is. You can make a pointer to absolutely any variable even outside of your program (however this is dangerous and may also crash your app). Pointer is just a number, address in memory. There are many cases where you point to global/local variable. For example if you want to pass class/array to some function.

Comment: yeah this book has some mistakes. that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

A pointer can point to local variables or global variables (or fields inside them). But you might prefer [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) in that case.

A pointer can also point to memory obtained by some ad-hoc mechanism. For instance, the `::operator new` on Linux would indirectly call [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (or similar system calls) which grows the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your process. Or in some embedded processors you have special primitives to get some memory (e.g. switch [memory banks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_bank)), etc...

A pointer can also point to some address outside of your virtual address space. Then dereferencing it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and often gives a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

However, it is often (but not always) considered bad taste to point to local or global data. It is often simpler to code with the convention that pointers should be to heap allocated memory. Read also about [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) (notably [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) and [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting).

<sup>(there *are* some excellent reasons to use pointers to *local* data on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) or to global data, but that should be done with caution and care; I leave you to find out more about them, perhaps by studying existing C++ source code - e.g. of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software))</sup>

Read also about [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer). You should avoid both of them. On Linux and POSIX systems, learn about [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (a tool to help hunting memory related bugs).

The terminology and concepts of [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) are useful to know.

A common style might be (for pointers stored in fields of classes or structures) to allocate memory for them with `new` in constructors and to release with `delete` in destructors.

Comment: Short-term pointers to locals are not bad, particularly when passing to something that will use it polymorphically. (Though references would probably be the better way to go.)

Comment: Pointers to local variables are very common in recurrences functions.

Comment: I did say "not always"

Comment: Right, my comment was directed more at future readers who might want to know an example of "but not always."

Answer (score 0):

Pointers can point to any object, such that statement "The value to which it points, however, resides in the heap" is at least incomplete, actually wrong. A pointer can point to any object, regardless of whether it resides on a "stack", on a "heap" or on same "fixed" memory, and regardless of whether it is a "global variable" or a "local variable". Note that all these terms are imprecise and not even used in the standard in the context of objects or pointers. The standard just talks about [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) of objects (automatic, static, dynamic), and about the [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) (i.e. visibility) of the variable name (block, function, namespace, global namespace,...).

So the only important thing is that a pointer can point to **any** object, regardless of its storage duration, **but** it must not be "used" (i.e. dereferenced) before the lifetime of the object it points to has begun or after the lifetime has ended. Otherwise, the behaviour of your program is undefined.

BTW: regardless of how old your book is, there has not been any C++ standard where the statement "points always to the heap" has been true.

Comment: Pointers can even contain addresses outside of the address space

Comment: That's true, pointer is just a number. You can set it to anything you want however you shouldn't expect it will work with any random number :)